# GKSession over WiFi disconnects when router rotates security keys

Tags: ios, wifi, gksession

This issue is baffling to me.

I am using GKSession over WiFi in a host-client spoke configuration for my app. But for some reason, whenever the router rotates its security keys, the devices all get disconnected from each other. I have tested repeatedly and have verified that the session is still valid, but the devices remain disconnected.

Has anyone else experienced this problem? What did you do to resolve it?

Any ideas at all?

Comment: Reconnect. Would also be interesting to know what router this is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never was able to figure out why this was happening, but I did find a way to overcome the issue. I added some code to my app so that when it gets disconnected for a reason other than the user intentionally disconnecting, it will automatically try to reconnect. So far, this has resolved my issue.